# Lock code game puzzle

Tags: game, locks

I'm trying to solve a lock 3 code game, **[Can You Crack The Code](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SevenFeb.CanYouCrackTheCode)**. From time to time I find myself presented with a puzzle that has 2 possible solutions, but the game only allows one correct answer. For example, in the puzzle shown below, the possibilities I narrowed down are:

> 8 1 0   or   8 0 9

and I can't figure out which one is correct.

[image: Help]

How do I know which answer to give?

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE! I'd advise you to read the [tour page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). Further, puzzles taken from elsewhere must provide an attribution to the original source, or they risk being deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crack the lock code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46871/crack-the-lock-code) only numbers are diffrerent, even text is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the puzzle is taken from a game https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SevenFeb.CanYouCrackTheCode&hl=es and as Oray said i found the same post wich is the same game. 
ive been trying to make a javascript solver for this code because the game repeats the rules and only changes the numbers. but there are certain conbinations that i get 2 results possibles.

Comment: from the answer provided by jonMark im stuck in the same problem.

Comment: @SebastianCardenas You should edit the attribution into the puzzle post.  If the game presents this puzzle as shown, with the guesses already pre-filled, and you're supposed to use them to solve the code, then you should explain that as well (it's not obvious from the post if those were game-supplied or player-supplied guesses). If pre-filled, this game is bad—it's not possible to determine, short of by guessing, which of the equally valid possibilities is intended.

Answer (score 8):

> Clues 1 and 5 tell you 8 is in the answer. Clue 2 puts 8 first, and with clues 3 and 4, we know 0 is in the answer. Clue 5 says one of the others is 1 or 9, and you are right - there isn't enough information to decide between 809 and 810.

Answer (score 0):

I've concluded that

> Two answers are valid: 
>    - 810 
>    - 809 
>  
>  Summarizing the 5 conidtions (the 5 boxes) where rows are the possible numbers. x means not a valid digit at the given place for sure. 
>  X/Y means X of the Y cases. Light green: possible digit Light red: possible "not"
>  
>  
>  [image] 
>  
>  It reduces the the options for the first 3 conditions: 
>  [image] 
>  
>  Based on the 419 condition we can go with: 
>    1. ?1? 
>    2. ??9 
>  [image] 
>  
>  Let's see the ?1? branch: 9 is out then: 
>  [image] 
>  
>  Gives two options:81? or ?18: 
>  [image] 
>  
>  81? leads to 810 which works: 
>  [image] 
>  
>  ?18 leads to conflict: 
>  [image] 
>  
>  The ??9 branch: number 1 is out, then 8?9 then 809: 
>  [image] 
>  
>  Also this method proves that no other solutions exists. 
>  Yellow: the new changes 
>  Gray: changes due to new changes 
>  Blue: number and place identified 
>  Red: conflict

Comment: 839 conflicts with clue #2.  319 conflicts with clue #1.

Comment: Yes, I've realized this as well. TY. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> 809

Because:

> 547 is not in code then 1,9,3,8,0 comes 3 is not beacause it is wrong placed and last code is 809 is correct

Answer (score -3):

> 809 is the answer. The first clue states that "one number is correct and well placed", and the first clue was occupied by **9**, so **809** is the answer.

Comment: That ... doesn't exclude the other possibility at all.  810 also would have `one number is correct and well placed`.